# why Javascript function executes only once inside a php loop?

Tags: javascript, php, loops, while-loop

I have the **HideCheckbox()** function to be executed inside a php loop.

the main point is to hide the checkbox every time the div loads.

However, the checkbox will be hidden only in the first div.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function HideCheckbox() {
            document.getElementById("deleteCarCheckbox").style.display = "none";
        }
</script>
<?php
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

            try{
                $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
                $sql = mysqli_query($link,"a sql query");
                while ($donnees = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

?>
<div class="block-car">
<input type="checkbox" id="deleteCarCheckbox" name="deleteCar" style="float:right">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        HideCheckbox();
        </script>



<?php
         }
        catch(Exception $e){die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());}
       }
?>
```

Comment: ID **should** be _UNIQUE_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the value of `id` field must be unique, the code below should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function HideCheckbox(i) {
    document.getElementById("deleteCarCheckbox" + i).style.display = "none";
}
</script>

<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

try{
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
    $sql = mysqli_query($link,"a sql query");
    $i = 1;
    while ($donnees = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

        ?>
        <div class="block-car">
        <input type="checkbox" id="deleteCarCheckbox<?php echo $i; ?>" name="deleteCar" style="float:right">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            HideCheckbox(<?php echo $i; ?>);
        </script>



        <?php
        $i++;
    }
    catch(Exception $e){die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());}
}
?>
```

Comment: But if you just want to hide the checkbox remove your javascripts and do this: `<input type="checkbox" id="deleteCarCheckbox" name="deleteCar" style="float: right; display: none;">`

Comment: Thank you so much for the trick, and for the easy way to do it as well... I didn't know that it can be done using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This is because all your `checkbox` elements have the same **id**, and your javascript code only sets the `display` of the first occurrence, and since all your `checkboxes` have the same **id**, then it will only hide the first `checkbox`. Instead, make every `checkbox` have a *unique id*.

Answer (score 0):

`HideCheckbox()` is running multiple times, the issue is that is always hiding `deleteCarCheckbox`
To confirm that the loop is actually working try logging things onto the console and you will see when it gets called.

```
function HideCheckbox() {
    document.getElementById("deleteCarCheckbox").style.display = "none";
    console.log('HideCheckbox was called');
}
```

Also, the id attribute always needs to be unique. See here: [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)